# Postgresql: how to limit user's ability to allocate work_mem

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find a way to limit a risk of possible outage caused by Out Of Memory. My consern is that parameter `work_mem` can be adjusted by user on session level. It means that some user can set the value too high and some non-optimal query can cause the problem on production system.

Is there any way in Postgresql to limit user's ability to adjust `work_mem` to avoid that risk?

I was hoping to find something like `pga_aggregate_limit` in Oracle but looks like there is no similar parameters in Postgresql. At least in v12.

Comment: Not directly.  It wouldn't be too hard to hack a limit into the system and recompile, assuming you are set up to compile in the first place.  But the best way to deal with users doing dangerous things is by making them ex-users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution to limit directly work_mem but you could try to use my extension pg_set_acl https://github.com/pierreforstmann/pg_set_acl that allows to restrict SET command.

For example:

```
testdb=# \c testdb postgres
You are now connected to database "testdb" as user "postgres".
testdb=# create extension pg_set_acl;
CREATE EXTENSION
testdb=# \c testdb testuser;
You are now connected to database "testdb" as user "testuser".
testdb=> select * from set_acl.privs;
 privilege | parameter_name | user_name 
-----------+----------------+-----------
(0 rows)

testdb=> set work_mem='1GB';
ERROR:  pg_set_acl: permission denied for (work_mem,testuser)
testdb=> \c testdb postgres
You are now connected to database "testdb" as user "postgres".
testdb=# select set_acl.grant('work_mem','testuser');
 grant 
-------
 t
(1 row)

testdb=# \c testdb testuser;
You are now connected to database "testdb" as user "testuser".
testdb=> select * from set_acl.privs;
 privilege | parameter_name | user_name 
-----------+----------------+-----------
 SET       | work_mem       | testuser
(1 row)

testdb=> set work_mem='1GB';
SET
testdb=> show work_mem;
 work_mem 
----------
 1GB
(1 row)

testdb=>
```

Comment: Thats interesting. I also tried to find the way to restrict user from using `SET ` command. Thank you @pifor:)